# Need to find a way to use port 80

Tags: apache, xampp, port

I'm trying to use Xamp but my port 80 is being used by System. What do I do now ? Considering I don't want to change Xamp/Apache port.

Edit. I found that from Admin Tools. PID 4 but when I go to Task Manager to shut it down no service shows PID 4.

Comment: What do you get if you point a browser to port 80?

Comment: Are you using Skype? Skype sometimes occupies port 80.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson How do I do that? I'm using Skype. But it's shut down when I try to use Xamp.Plus from Admin tools it says System occupies it.

Comment: @user1355564 Type `http://localhost/` in your browser on that machine.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson sorry but it says that this resource couldn't be found. Error 404

Answer (score 0):

When utilities show System using port 80, it's probably actually IIS. (No, I don't know why.)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows “World Wide Publishing Service is using this port and stopping this service will free the port 80 and you can connect Apache using this port. To stop the service go to the “Task manager –> Services tab”, right click the “World Wide Publishing Service” and stop.

If you don't find there then Then go to "Run > services.msc" and again find there and right click the “World Wide Publishing Service” and stop.

If you didn't find “World Wide Publishing Service” there then go to "Run>>resmon.exe>> Network Tab>>Listening Ports" and see which process is using port 80

[image]

And from "Overview>>CPU" just Right click on that process and click "End Process Tree". If that process is system that might be a critical issue.